# Cypress If element exists + contains

Tags: cypress

I am trying to create easy `if/else` statement with `contains` function. However when I use `contains` it always waits for the element even tho it's in the if statement.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div data-testid="upload">
   </div>
      <table>
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th>Name</th>
               <th>Status</th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td>test 1.txt</td>
               <th>uploaded</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td>test 2.txt</td>
               <th>failure</th>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
</div>
```

**WORKING CYPRESS WITHOUT `cy.contains`**

```
cy.get('div[data-testid="upload"]').then($modal => {
    if ($modal.is(':visible')) {
        cy.wait(100000)
    } else {
        cy.wait(200000)
    }
})
```

**DOES NOT WORK WITH `cy.contains`**

```
cy.get('div[data-testid="upload"]').then($modal => {
    if ($modal.contains('failure').is(':visible')) {
        cy.wait(100000)
    } else {
        cy.wait(200000)
    }
})
```

It **works** when `failure` text **is visible**, but it's **not working** when the text **is not visible**, any idea how to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: The `.contains()` you're using is actually JQuery's `.contains()` and not `cy.contains()`. The `cy.get()` yields a JQueryHTMLElement. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.contains/

Comment: thanks for the heads up, however I tried this `if(cy.wrap($modal).contains('failure').is(':visible')) {...}` and it did not help :-(

Comment: `cy` functions should not be used like that, as they don't yield truthy/falsy values in a useful manner for conditionals.